# sendmail.php does not work on mobile

Tags: php, wordpress, mobile

Strange issue - my sendmail.php is working perfectly on desktop and on **mobile devices only when requesting desktop websites** (in Chrome app), but when using mobile site he does not work at all.

**Can someone help me figure this out?**

here is the code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    if (!check_email($_POST['email'])) 
    {
        echo 'Please enter a valid email address<br />';
    }
    else send_email();
}
exit;

function check_email($emailAddress) {
    if (filter_var($emailAddress, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      return TRUE;
    } else {
      return FALSE;
    }
}
function send_email() {
    $message = "\nName: " . $_POST['name'] .
        "\nEmail: " . $_POST['email'] ;

    $message .= "\nMessage: " . $_POST['comment'] .
        "\n\nBrowser Info: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] .
        "\nIP: " . $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] .
        "\n\nDate: " . date("Y-m-d h:i:s");

    $siteEmail = $_POST['receiver'];
    $emailTitle = $_POST['subject'];
    $thankYouMessage = "Thank you for contacting us, we'll get back to you shortly.";   

    if(!mail($siteEmail, $emailTitle, $message, 'From: ' . $_POST['name'] . ' <' . $_POST['email'] . '>'))
        { 
            echo 'error';
        }
    else 
    { 
        echo 'success'; 
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: This is probably a problem with the HTML on the mobile version of your site and not a problem with you PHP code. My guess is your mobile site does not properly set and/or POST `email` and so the isset() check fails. Perhaps you can add an `else` clause to your initial `if` to verify this.

Comment: Either the button or the code around the button (the `<form>`).

Comment: @TomDworzanski - Thanks! I think you are right. It is look like the issue is regarding the button - when trying to send form with the mobile site (even from desktop) the form does not work.
** Do you have any idea how to solve it?
** Can it be related to jquery?

Comment: This is the code part related to mobile, maybe it could help: http://prntscr.com/73w2lx

Comment: Everything there looks okay. You are sending using POST and you have a field named email.

Comment: Perhaps you can look at the HTML after has rendered in your browser? Every browser has a `View Source` option. Try to find the `<form>` and make sure things are set right.

Comment: I've looked over the HTML and I think I found the issue:
'<input type="submit" name="send_mail" id="send_mail" value="submit">' this code does not work (show only on mobile).
While, this code: <button class="button nice secondary" id="submitinput" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button> is working.

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure the mobile form has these two elements:

1. It is being submitted using `method="POST"`.
2. Your email input has the attribute and value `name="email"`.

I demonstrate where these things are set in the following code. This is incomplete, of course, it's just designed to show you where the two required parts must be.

```
<form ... method="POST">
...
    <input type="text" name="email" ... >
...
</form>
```

---

*I need to mention one more thing ...*

That being said, what you're doing here is ***EXTREMELY INSECURE***. You are allowing someone to set an email's from and two address on a web form. A (not so) clever hacker can easily write a script to turn your server into an open relay for spam or other evil activities. At minimum, you should remove `$_POST['receiver']` and replace with with a hard-coded email address or at least not something that can be altered by an end-user when they POST to your form.

Answer (score 0):

So I drilled down and found that the mobile form is directing submissions through this PHP file which was 404.
The issue now is, even when this file is avaiable, emails are not sent...

> ' . "\r\n"; $headers .=
>   'From: ' . "\r\n"; $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' .
>   "\r\n"; $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
>   
>   $message .= "Name: " . $name . "
> "; $message .= "Subject: "
>   . $subject . "
> "; $message .= "Email: " . $email . "
> "; $message .= "Message: " . $message_text . "
> ";
>   
>   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, "-f noreplay@info.com");
>   
>   echo 1; }
>   
>   if(isset($_POST['sendmail']) && $_POST['sendmail'] == 1){
>     send_mail(); } ?>